# How to identify the clicked table cell in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

In HTML/JavaScript code I dynamically generate a table with various elements. The first column consists of elements of type `img` to which I add a callback when a user clicks on one such image.

In the callback, how can I figure out the row of the image the user clicked on?

Do I have to use the element `event.target.currentSrc` (which contains the path to the image source) to figure that out? Or is there a better way to get the row of the image that has been clicked?

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="modal-content">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <table id="myTable" class="aircraftTable"><thead>
            <tr><th>Type</th><th>Cost</th><th>Range</th><th>Seats</th><th>Consumption</th></tr>
            <tr><td><img src="static/img/A320neo.jpg" width="100"><br>A320 neo</td><td>97000000</td><td>5200</td><td>150</td><td>2.43</td></tr>
            <tr><td><img src="static/img/B787-10.jpg" width="100"><br>B787-10</td><td>270000000</td><td>15000</td><td>246</td><td>2.37</td></tr>
        </thead></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you think about the `.dataSet` use?

Comment: Never heard of that before. I do not have a lot of experience in javascript

Comment: The other question. How did you render this table? Dynamically? Is there any loop?

Comment: `event.target.closest('tr')` gives you the row. `event.target` property of PointerEvent is inherited from [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), that's why you don't see it in the docs of PointerEvent.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for that, but is there a way to get the row number?

Comment: @AksenP Yes there is a loop

Comment: The row itself contains `rowIndex` property.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks a lot! Can you maybe give me a link to where that is documented? I cannot find `target` documented under `PointEvent`...

Comment: ?? There already is a link to the Event interface in my comment above. Or did you mean docs of [rowIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) ..?

Comment: <img src="static/img/A320neo.jpg" data-id=“1234” onclick=“myFunction(this.dataset.id)” width="100">

Comment: @Teemu I was looking at the documentation of `PointerEvent`. So in order to know all properties of this class you have to look at ALL the inherited instances, so in this case `MouseEvent`, `UIEvent` and `Event`. Isn't there a form of documentation which also includes all the inherited attributes & methods? Seems a bit painful to check all the parent classes...

Comment: That's the way the contributors at MDN have chosen for the documentation. AFAIK that's the best available documentation for JS/DOM, so probably no.

Comment: @Teemu Ok fair enough. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) property you can use.

In this example I've attached one event listener to the table body element which catches events from its child elements (thanks to [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). When a table cell is clicked on the code finds the [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) row element, and then grabs its index.

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

tbody.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('td')) {
    const row = e.target.closest('tr');
    console.log(row.rowIndex);
  }
}
```

```css
th, td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 0.5em; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1.1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>2.1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>3.1</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```